# WebRequest equivalent of `curl -X DELETE ...`

Tags: c#, .net, curl, couchdb

I'm having trouble with creating a WebRequest equivalent of the following curl command:

```
curl -vX DELETE "http://admin:123@localhost:5984/booster"
```

The command works fine, gives the following output:

```
C:\Projects\Booster\Bin>curl -vX DELETE "http://admin:123@localhost:5984/booster"
* About to connect() to localhost port 5984 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> DELETE /booster HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTIz
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
> Host: localhost:5984
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: CouchDB/1.0.2 (Erlang OTP/R14B)
< Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2011 01:03:45 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 12
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate
<
{"ok":true}
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

and deletes a CouchDB database as expected, though when I use the following equivalent code:

```
try
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create("http://admin:123@localhost:5984/booster");

    request.Headers.Clear();
    request.Method = "DELETE";

    var response = request.GetResponse();

    Console.WriteLine(response.GetResponseString());
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Response.GetResponseString());
}
```

To do the same as the curl command, I get an Exception telling

"The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed."

Server responds with '{"error":"method_not_allowed","reason":"Only GET,HEAD allowed"}'

## The Question:

What the difference between curl command and the command executed via WebRequest? Why in first case everything works and in second everything fails?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but you could use Wireshark or possibly Fiddler as a diagnostic tool to look at what is transpiring on the wire.

Comment: I've installed Wireshark I can't understand anything, can you give some links to some quick start tuts?

Comment: Have you tried setting the [Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials.aspx) property instead of specifying `admin:123` in the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to figure out what was the problem, so here goes:

Wireshark shown the following communication between client and server:

## The WebRequest case

```
DELETE /booster HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5984
Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: CouchDB/1.0.2 (Erlang OTP/R14B)
Location: http://localhost:5984/_utils/session.html?return=%2Fbooster&reason=You%20are%20not%20a%20server%20admin.
Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2011 09:54:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 64
Cache-Control: must-revalidate

{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"You are not a server admin."}
DELETE /_utils/session.html?return=%2Fbooster&reason=You%20are%20not%20a%20server%20admin. HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5984

HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server: CouchDB/1.0.2 (Erlang OTP/R14B)
Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2011 09:54:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 64
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Allow: GET,HEAD

{"error":"method_not_allowed","reason":"Only GET,HEAD allowed"}
```

## The curl case

```
DELETE /booster HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTIz
User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
Host: localhost:5984
Accept: */*

HTTP/1.1 404 Object Not Found
Server: CouchDB/1.0.2 (Erlang OTP/R14B)
Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2011 09:54:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 41
Cache-Control: must-revalidate

{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}
```

It shows that WebRequest doesn't use Basic authorization, and curl does use one. Little bit of googling shown the way to use basic authorization on WebRequest and it looks like the following:

```
try
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:5984/booster");

    request.Headers.Clear();

    request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("admin:123"));
    request.Method = "DELETE";

    var response = request.GetResponse();

    Console.WriteLine(response.GetResponseString());
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Response.GetResponseString());
}
```

Comment: Grats on figuring it out!  I guess you don't need those Wireshark tutorials now...  :P

Comment: You could also use:
      request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "123");